# IE10 does not display my gradient over my background

Tags: html, css, background, internet-explorer-10, gradient

I am using an gradient with opacity as an brightness effect for JUST my background. Now it works in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't seem to work in IE10, but I did put the -ms- version there.

Here is my JSFiddle: [>>>JSFiddle<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg7Ap/)

Here is the code:

```
<div id="lol">

</div>
```

-

```
#lol {
    background-image:url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
    width:700px;
    height:465px;
}

#lol:hover {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%), url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,.1))), url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%), url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%), url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%), url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 100%), url('http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/PhotoDiscFrontdoor/StaticContent/fd_image_test.jpg');
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code? Why doesn't it work in Internet Explorer 10?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works in IE10 on Win7, same effect as in Chrome and FF

Comment: Your fiddle works for me on IE10 and Win8.

Comment: Works fine here as well (IE10 + Win8).

Comment: Mmmmh, it doesnt work in regular IE10, only when I look at it trough JSFiddle.

Comment: IE10 adds these CSS values, could they somehow interfer with the effect?:



 background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
 background-position-x: 0%, 0%;
 background-position-y: 0%, 0%;
 background-size: auto, auto;
 background-origin: padding-box, padding box;
 background-clip: border-box, border-box;
 background-color: transparent;